# Full text search not working in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a search functionality in PHP/MySQL.

I am using Full text search
Here is my query : `SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH(prod_title,prod_long_desc) AGAINST('candles' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)`

**But the problem is when I am going to search with '**candle**' it's working but when I am going to search with '**candles**', its not working.**

*Into my database table I have '**candle**' keyword not 'candles'.*

I am stuck with it.
If you have any solution, it will be great.

Thank you.

Comment: try removing  IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE

Comment: not working. I removed that.

Comment: since you say "Into my database table I have 'candle' keyword not 'candles'." so use candle in against('candle')

Comment: How large is the dataset, and what percentage of rows would satisfy the criteria? And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: only 10 data I have.. But the problem is Is it possible to find candles keyword ? but into my database table I dont have candles keyword. I only have candle

Comment: A mysql fulltext search looks for exact word matches. You can use wildcards though, e.g. `candle*`, so you may simply want to allow the user to enter wildcards to find both. You can try to replace user input automatically, but that will get complicated really fast if you want to e.g. support singular versions of "men", "wives" or "mice". If you need this feature, you may want to look for (or write) a package or search engine that supports [Stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming).